# I want to be able to formulate a question about X3C-algorithm; while being question banned. And wait until the ban is over

Tags: feature-request

[x3c-solver using string comparisons and nested loops](https://pastebin.com/mV6eeihA)

I found a great on-topic question for this site that could be of great value.

### Question

Can I at least be able to write a question and not be able to post it until the ban is lifted?

Comment: You cannot write the question on SE while having a question ban, but you could use an external markdown editor (e.g. https://stackedit.io/ ), to write your question there, save the file locally, and then copy the markdown source later.

Comment: @Discretelizard Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can create a post here. So open a new post here. write your text. You have the same formatting possibility as on the main site. You  can view your formatted post here without actually posting it. Save your text in a local file using a text editor and discard your post here. You can also use [Formatting Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370/11206) or [Sandbox for drafts of long, complex posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666/11206) if you are able to post on math.meta.stackexchange.com.